# Opening memory-mapped file with encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding, memory-mapped-files

[Memory mapped file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) is an efficient way for using regex or doing manipulation on large binary files.

In case I have a large text file (~1GB), is it possible to work with an encoding-aware mapped file?
Regex like `[\u1234-\u5678]` won't work on `bytes` objects and converting the pattern to unicode will not work either (as `"[\u1234-\u5678]".encode("utf-32")`  for example will not understand the range correctly).
Searching might work if I convert the search pattern from `str` to `bytes` using `.encode()` but it's still somewhat limited and there should be a simpler way instead of decoding and encoding all day.

I have tried wrapping it with `io.TextIOWrapper` inside an `io.BufferedRandom` but to no avail:

```
AttributeError: 'mmap.mmap' object has no attribute 'seekable'
```

Creating a wrapper (using inheritance) and setting the methods `seekable`, `readable` and `writable` to return `True` did not work either.

Regarding encoding, a fixed length encoding like `utf-32`, code-points or the lower BMP of `utf-16` (if it's even possible referring just to that part) might be assumed.

Solution is welcome for any python version.

Comment: With variable-length encodings like UTF-8, there's no way to tell where character 50000 is without going through the 49999 characters before it, defeating the purpose of memory-mapping. You might find something that works for fixed-length encodings.

Comment: @user2357112 Thought it might pose a problem but for the sake of the question, a fixed length like `utf-16`, `utf-32` or code-points might be assumed.

Comment: UTF-16 is still variable-length, and in any case, it's the encoding of the file that's the issue, not the encoding of the pattern.

Comment: @user2357112 updated to specify `utf-32` or the lower BMP of `utf-16` if it's even possible referring just to that part. And yes, the encoding of the file is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without essentially reinventing the wheel from scratch (writing all new versions of the `re` module, the `mmap` module, etc.), or writing extraordinarily complex regexes that can't use the niceties of stuff like true Unicode character ranges (you'd have an alternation between three different patterns to make `[\u1234-\u5678]`, something like `(?:\x12[\x34-\xff]|[\x13-\x55].|\x56[\x00-\x78])`).

Basically, `re` patterns only work with `str`, or work with `bytes`-like objects (and you can't try to work around it with `memoryview`s and casts, because `re` still treats it as bytes, not larger types).

For simple searches, you could try using [`mmap.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) after encoding the string to use for searching, but that's still prone to subtle bugs; for UCS-2 or UTF-32, you'd need to check that the return value from `find` was aligned on a two or four byte boundary respectively to ensure you didn't mistake the end of one character and the beginning of the next for a completely different character. If the alignment test failed, you'd have to repeat the search with a `start` offset of the last return value + 1 until you either got a hit or `find` returned `-1`. It's just not a reasonable thing to do in the general case.

Comment: The regex should be `(?:\x12[\x34-\xff]|[\x13-\x55].)|(?:\x56[\x00-\x78])` btw.

Comment: @Bharel: That pattern you gave would be equivalent to `[\u1234-\u55ff][\u5600-\u5678]` wouldn't it? Two different classes for different ranges, not one class covering the whole range. Of course, it would still only work if the data was big endian UCS-2; you'd have to flip the contents of each alternation if it were little endian.

Comment: My bad, It will just be the same. I also forgot the endian-ness. What a mess. Anyway, it sounds rather unfortunate if you're correct regarding the fact it doesn't exist but I'll be waiting for another answer. I believe I'm not the first who thought of using mmap on text files (or at least I hope I'm not). If non arise in a reasonable time I'll *accept* this answer as my fate.

Comment: @Bharel: You're not the first to think of it, because I know I tried to figure out if this was possible a couple years back. :-) I tried a ton of approaches, but `mmap`s can't do multi-byte, `memoryview`s, even `cast` to different sizes, still act like `bytes` with `re` `bytes` patterns, and `re` `str` patterns work solely with `str` (and `unicode` on Py2), not arbitrary types.

Comment: Well then, I guess we're all doomed :-( Perhaps you should contact your friends at Microsoft to supply us a smart WinAPI for encoded mmaps :P  I'll still wait patiently for a miraculous answer I guess.

Comment: @Bharel: You're welcome to do so, but I'll be incredibly surprised if anything comes of it.